# How to create sub child menu from a json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, css

I created a horizontal menu from a json file. But I can't create the child and subchild. When I create the child of administrator it goes to home's child. My javascript file is

```
var data = [{
    "menu":[
        {
            "MenuId":1,
            "MenuName":"Home",
            "MenuLink":null,
            "Action":null,
            "Controller":null,
            "ParentID":null,
            "SortOrder":1,
            "ModuleId":null,
            "Menus":{
            }
        },
        {
            "MenuId":2,
            "MenuName":"New Transaction",
            "MenuLink":null,
            "Action":null,
            "Controller":null,
            "ParentID":null,
            "SortOrder":2,
            "ModuleId":null,
            "Menus":{
            }
        },
        {
            "MenuId":3,
            "MenuName":"Portfolio",
            "MenuLink":null,
            "Action":null,
            "Controller":null,
            "ParentID":null,
            "SortOrder":3,
            "ModuleId":null,
            "Menus":{
            }
        },
        {
            "MenuId":4,
            "MenuName":"Analytics",
            "MenuLink":null,
            "Action":null,
            "Controller":null,
            "ParentID":null,
            "SortOrder":4,
            "ModuleId":null,
            "Menus":{
            }
        },
        {
            "MenuId":5,
            "MenuName":"Instructions",
            "MenuLink":null,
            "Action":null,
            "Controller":null,
            "ParentID":null,
            "SortOrder":5,
            "ModuleId":null,
            "Menus":{
            }
        },
        {
            "MenuId":6,
            "MenuName":"Data Upload",
            "MenuLink":null,
            "Action":null,
            "Controller":null,
            "ParentID":null,
            "SortOrder":6,
            "ModuleId":null,
            "Menus":{
            }
        },
        {
            "MenuId":7,
            "MenuName":"Administration",
            "MenuLink":null,
            "Action":null,
            "Controller":null,
            "ParentID":null,
            "SortOrder":7,
            "ModuleId":null,
            "Menus":[
                {
                    "MenuId":8,
                    "MenuName":"Masters",
                    "MenuLink":null,
                    "Action":null,
                    "Controller":null,
                    "ParentID":7,
                    "SortOrder":1,
                    "ModuleId":null,
                    "Menus":[
                        {
                            "MenuId":10,
                            "MenuName":"Currency",
                            "MenuLink":"/Currencies/Index",
                            "Action":"Index",
                            "Controller":"Currencies",
                            "ParentID":8,
                            "SortOrder":1,
                            "ModuleId":null,
                            "Menus":{
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "MenuId":11,
                            "MenuName":"Country",
                            "MenuLink":"/Countries/Index",
                            "Action":"Index",
                            "Controller":"Countries",
                            "ParentID":8,
                            "SortOrder":2,
                            "ModuleId":null,
                            "Menus":{
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "MenuId":9,
                    "MenuName":"User Management",
                    "MenuLink":null,
                    "Action":null,
                    "Controller":null,
                    "ParentID":7,
                    "SortOrder":2,
                    "ModuleId":null,
                    "Menus":{
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
];
$(function() {
for(var i = 0, j = data[0].menu.length; i<j; i++) {
    var root_menu = data[0].menu[i];
    if(root_menu.hasOwnProperty("MenuId")) {
        $("#menu").append('<li><a href="#" class="parent-menu">' + root_menu.MenuName + '</a>');
        if(root_menu.hasOwnProperty("Menus") && root_menu.Menus.length > 0) {
            $("#menu li").append("<ul class='child-list' id='menu_" + root_menu.MenuId + "'>");
            for(var n = 0, m = root_menu.Menus.length; n<m; n++) {
                var sub_menu = root_menu.Menus[n];
                if(sub_menu.hasOwnProperty("MenuId")) {
                    $("#menu_" + root_menu.MenuId).append("<li class='menu-child'><a href='#'>" + sub_menu.MenuName + "</a></li>");

                }
            }

        }
 $("#menu").append("</ul></li>");

    }
}
});
```

You can check my code from http://jsfiddle.net/JcU4G/9/ Here the child also has a sub child. How can i arrange the child and sub child from a json file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are looping through and adding the li elements to the main menu you can simply use .last()

```
$("#menu li").last().append("<ul class='child-list' id='menu_" + root_menu.MenuId + "'>");
```

this will append the submenu to the right main menu item =)

**Edit:**
To add another sub-sub menu add something along this lines:

```
if(sub_menu.hasOwnProperty("Menus") && sub_menu.Menus.length > 0){
                    $("#menu_" + root_menu.MenuId + " li").last().append("<ul class='child-list' id='menu_" + sub_menu.MenuId + "'>");
                    for(var oo = 0, pp = sub_menu.Menus.length; oo<pp; oo++){
                        var subsub_menu = sub_menu.Menus[oo];
                        $("#menu_" + sub_menu.MenuId).append("<li></li>")
                    }
                    $("#menu_" + root_menu.MenuId + " li").last().append("</ul>");
                }
```

of course you have to straighten the styling now ... to display the subsub_menu items propperly.
here is a fiddle where i forked your example and stripped it of the style: [jsfiddle.net/HPNkq](http://jsfiddle.net/HPNkq)

Considering that you are new to programming i did not want to rewrite your whole code, but just added the bit the same way you were already coding. However, i would approach such a problem by defining a function that bilds a menu level and recursively calls itself again if an item has a submenu.

Comment: no problem, just check if this sub element has item Menus like you did on the root_menu ... and the same logic applies again with last.

Comment: when you are in your sub menu ... check if it contains object Menus ... if so loop through its contents ... I added some code to my answer ... just you have to add css to the new elements.

Comment: if you don't mind you just put that code in the fiddle and send me the link.. I am new in programming field.

Comment: here is a version that works - i took the style off, but an even more http://jsfiddle.net/HPNkq/ but an even more flexible version would be by using a recursive function - so that you don't need to hardcode the loop for each level of nesting

Comment: -Do you know about responsive design?